# how to load json file using python (not manually)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

code :

```
userid1='u123'
userid2='u124'
ids= (userid1,userid2)

fake = Faker('en_US')

for ind in ids:

        for idx in range(1):

        sms =  {
            "id": ind ,
            "name": fake.name(),
            "email": fake.email(),
            "gender": "MALE",
                     }

    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
    with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
     #Save the dictionary
    json.dump(sms, fp, indent=4)
    print(sms)



file1 = filename.json ( how to get the *ind* value here i.e., userid)
fd1=open("filename.json")
json_content1 = fd1.read()
fd1.close()
```

how to open  file that has been saved  `f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)` here . without mentioning the file name manually.   file names are saved using *ind*.  so how to use ind here and open the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code can help you to get data from json file: you can get any filed from the json data by typing  data["name-of-filed"]:

```
import json

userid1='json_file1'
ids= [userid1]


for ind in ids:

    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)    
    with open(f_name, 'r') as outfile:
        data = json.loads(outfile.read())
    print(data["name"])
    print(data)
```

here is an exemple :

```
file.json :
{
    "name": "Ghassen",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
}
```

output :

```
Ghassen
{'name': 'Ghassen', 'apiVersion': 'v1'}
```

Comment: it has to take file name from ids from above

Comment: add the name of files in a list the iterate over it like this :

userid1='son_file1'
ids= [userid1]


for ind in ids:

    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
    with open(f_name, 'r') as outfile:

Comment: check the code above i already update it to read the file name from a list